# Create a list of many lists

Tags: python, list

I ran into some troubles when creating a list of 3 lists. Here is the code:

```
>>> li = [[]]*3
>>> li
[[], [], []]
>>> li[0].append(1)
>>> li
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

Why is the result not `[[1], [], []]`?